# SQL count longest consecutive days with dates table

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, common-table-expression

I have a login table with columns UserID and login_date like below (but with thousands of entries). How would I find the longest streak of consecutive log-ins for each user and what the start and end days were for those streaks?

Edit: Using Postgres. Removed question about streaks only counting M-F and not weekends (Do I make a separate post about that?)

```
UserID     login_date
112        2020-03-14
131        2020-07-26
112        2019-03-15
323        2019-02-28
639        2019-02-09
```

Comment: (1) Are there duplicates?  (2) Tag with the database you are using.  (3) As written, your question is too broad because you are asking multiple questions.

Comment: 1. I have no idea 2. using Postgres 3. Ok just asking the first question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this as a gap-and-islands problem.  Assuming one login per day (as in the example data), you can subtract an enumerated sequence, and the value is constant on consecutive days.

In Standard SQL, the logic for all sequences look like:

```
select userid, min(login_date), max(login_date)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by userid order by login_date) as seqn
      from t
     ) t
group by userid, login_date - seqnum * interval '1 day';
```

In Postgres, you can actually get the longest using `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (userid) userid, min(login_date), max(login_date)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by userid order by login_date) as seqn
      from t
     ) t
group by userid, login_date - seqnum * interval '1 day'
order by userid, count(*) desc;
```

Note:  If thee are duplicates for user/day combinations, use `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

If you want to handle weekends and holidays, then a calendar table is recommended.